# UIImage / NSData to Binary string conversation

Tags: objective-c, sdk, uiimage, ios5, nsdata

i have a image to post web service and i need to convert UIImage / NSData to binary string.
how i can do that?

Web service doesn't accept form data submission.

```
[urlRequest addData:xdata]
```

doesn't work.

Thank you & Best.

Comment: Post how you are creating urlRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to make that HTTP request using POST and append to the body of the request the binary data of your photo.

To do so:

```
NSURL * requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:...];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [NSData dataWithBytes:xData length:xDataLen];    
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",xDataLen] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"your/contenttype" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

You should change `xData`, `xDataLen` and `"your/contentype"` with your real data.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
[myImage data] // NSData
```

or `[myImage bytes] // void * bytes.`

Comment: -1: UIImage has no `data` or `bytes` methods. If you meant NSData instead: that one has no `data` method either. Also, it doesn't help the poster with sending his request.